# Replace cell reference in a formula via another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find a way to change a cell reference in a formula via another cell.  Let's say I have the formula =B1+C1 in cell A1.  Now I want to change the B1 to F1 by simply typing F into a separate cell.  How do I make the B in B1 a replaceable variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use *INDIRECT()*:

```
=INDIRECT(B2)+C1
```

[image]

Comment: @Sean, the question actually asks about entering just the column letter, so to expand a little on the answer: INDIRECT lets you build a cell reference from other cell references, formulas, text strings, etc.; anything that will evaluate to a cell reference inside INDIRECT's parentheses.  So if you want to enter just the column letter, it would look like: `=INDIRECT(B2&"1")+C1`.  The `&` concatenates the pieces and the `1` is used as literal text rather than a number, so it's in quotes.

Comment: Hello @fixer1234 - Thank you very much for the quick reply and I have actually seen that solution.  I should have been more clear because most of what I am trying to do is a mass update to a column in a formula.  Lets say that formula in my example continues down through row 100.  How would I change all of the "B" to "F"?

Comment: @Sean, so you want to lock the reference to B2, since that contains the column, and have the row reference reflect the row the formula is on?  The C1 portion of the formula will adjust as you copy it down, so you could use: =INDIRECT($B$2&ROW())+C1

Comment: @fixer, thanks again.  So basically I need to add the INDIRECT function into every row.  Since my file already exist I was hoping there was a way to reference the cells and the change that I wanted in one cell.  I can of course use the replace function to update the formulas.  Thanks!

Comment: @Sean, You need the INDIRECT function in every row.  But like any formula that you replicate, you enter it once and copy or drag it down to populate the column.